# Regex for matching everything before trailing slash, or first question mark?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that will elegantly match everything in an URL AFTER the domain name, and before the first ?, the last slash, or the end of the URL, if neither of the 2 exist.

This is what I came up with but it seems to be failing in some cases:

```
regex = /[http|https]:\/\/.+?\/(.+)[?|\/|]$/
```

In summary:

http://nytimes.com/2013/07/31/a-new-health-care-approach-dont-hide-the-price/ should return 
2013/07/31/a-new-health-care-approach-dont-hide-the-price

http://nytimes.com/2013/07/31/a-new-health-care-approach-dont-hide-the-price?id=2 should return 
2013/07/31/a-new-health-care-approach-dont-hide-the-price

http://nytimes.com/2013/07/31/a-new-health-care-approach-dont-hide-the-price should return 
2013/07/31/a-new-health-care-approach-dont-hide-the-price

Comment: Yes, a regex can accomplish this, but there is more to parsing and decoding a URL than the selected answer's regex can handle, especially when dealing with the query section if it's been encoded, or [IDNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) or anything that doesn't have the year at the beginning of the path. In other words, this is only a very specific fix working only on a small domain. Use well tested tools, such as URI or especially Addressable::URI instead, which handle all URLs and the RFCs and give you the needed ancillary code to handle encoding/decoding too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If lookaheads are allowed

```
((2[0-9][0-9][0-9].*)(?=\?\w+)|(2[0-9][0-9][0-9].*)(?=/\s+)|(2[0-9][0-9][0-9].*).*\w)
```

Copy + Paste this in http://regexpal.com/

See here with ruby regex tester: http://rubular.com/r/uoLLvTwkaz

Image using javascript regex, but it works out the same

[image]

`(?=)` is just a a lookahead

I basically set up three matches from 2XXX up to (in this *order*):

```
(?=\?\w+)  # lookahead for a question mark followed by one or more word characters
(?=/\s+)   # lookahead for a slash         followed by one or more whitespace characters
.*\w       # match up to the last word character
```

I'm pretty sure that some parentheses were not needed but I just copy pasted.

There are essentially two OR `|` expressions in the `(A|B|C)` expression.  The order matters since it's like a `(ifthen|elseif|else)` type deal.

You can probably fix out the prefix, I just assumed that you wanted 2XXX where X is a digit to match.

Also, save the pitchforks everyone, regular expressions are not always the best but it's there for you when you need it.

Also, there is xkcd (https://xkcd.com/208/) for everything:

[image: https://xkcd.com/208/]

Answer (score 8):

Please don't use Regex for this. Use the URI library:

```
require 'uri'
str_you_want = URI("http://nytimes.com/2013/07/31/a-new-health-care-approach-dont-hide-the-price").path
```

## Why?

See everything about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1) famous question for a good discussion of why these kinds of things are a bad idea.

Also, this XKCD really says why:
[image: Yep.]

In short, Regexes are an incredibly powerful tools, but when you're dealing with things that are made from hundred page convoluted standards when there is *already a library* for doing it faster, easier, and more correctly, why reinvent this wheel?

Comment: @squiguy: Thanks. (We all know that good answer is #42 on the list of voting priorities. I'm pretty sure that having XKCD is #5 ;) )

Comment: URI.new is giving me NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for URI:Module

Comment: Also, although I posted Ruby code, I need this regex in the database query as well, so I can't reuse this URI method in the database. So a regex is preferable. But this suffices for my Ruby code.

Comment: @HenleyChiu: Whoops! Try it again now.

Comment: As I am fond of saying: Regular expressions are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.

Comment: Regex is still the magic wand though. How do you think URI does it?

Comment: @pguardiario: See the source (it's in Ruby) [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/trunk/lib/uri).

Comment: @Linuxios - I've seen it. If you don't see regex there you need glasses.

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/uri/common.rb is chock-full of regex.